# Log4net creating custom levels

Tags: logging, log4net

I know its possible to use the built in levels with log4net
INFO, WARN, ERROR and FATAL messages

Is it possible to create new ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite a few years old now, but [this](http://www.l4ndash.com/Log4NetMailArchive%2Ftabid%2F70%2Fforumid%2F1%2Fpostid%2F14714%2Fview%2Ftopic%2FDefault.aspx) thread discusses what you are looking to do.

Comment: Link dead but available on [the internet archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20130528024223/http://www.l4ndash.com/Log4NetMailArchive/tabid/70/forumid/1/postid/14714/view/topic/Default.aspx)

Comment: And a few years later... both links are dead. Yay for link rot!

Answer (score 29):

This can be done with an extension method as outlined here: 
http://rageshkrishna.com/2011/01/21/AddingCustomLogLevelsToLog4net.aspx

> Adding some extension methods makes it dead simple to start using the
>   new log levels:

```cs
public static class SecurityExtensions
{
   static readonly log4net.Core.Level authLevel = new log4net.Core.Level(50000, "Auth");

   public static void Auth(this ILog log, string message)
   {
      log.Logger.Log(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType,
          authLevel, message, null);
   }

   public static void AuthFormat(this ILog log, string message, params object[] args)
   {
      string formattedMessage = string.Format(message, args);
      log.Logger.Log(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType,
          authLevel, formattedMessage, null);
   }

}
```

> And that’s it – now I can start using my new “Auth” logging level on
>   any instance of ILog like this:

```cs
SecurityLogger.AuthFormat("User logged in with id {0} from IP address {1}", id, Request.UserHostAddress);
```

Comment: Thank you for being the only answer to this question that isn't just a link.

Comment: For those wondering about Levels, here is paraphrased list of levels from log4net 2.07:
Off int.MaxValue,
Log4Net_Debug 120000,
Emergency 120000,
Fatal 110000,
Alert 100000,
Critical 90000,
Severe 80000,
Error 70000,
Warn  60000,
Notice  50000,
Info  40000,
Debug 30000,
Fine 30000,
Trace 20000,
Finer 20000,
Verbose 10000,
Finest 10000

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this to implement Verbose and/or Trace levels:

[Log4net, how to log a verbose message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279773/log4net-how-to-log-a-verbose-message/3461437#3461437)

Answer (score 0):

I stand corrected.  It's possible in log4j as well - I've just never done it:

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#custom-level

I would not have known unless I'd seen William's response and checked again.